# SQL Procedure with explicit cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi this is my first post so sorry if this has been asked before. I am trying to create a procedure that will add interest to the deposit account (for a specific bank) and output to the screen the customer names and new balances for deposit accounts.however i cant seem to get it to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addInterestNew(bank VARCHAR, interestRate INT out) AS
CURSOR CustomerBalance IS
SELECT customerName, balance
FROM Deposit
WHERE branchName = bank;


aCustomerName Deposit.customerName%TYPE;
newBalance  Deposit.balance%TYPE

BEGIN 
UPDATE DEPOSIT
SET balance = balance * (1 + (interestRate/100))
WHERE branchName = bank;

FETCH
OPEN CustomerBalance;
LOOP
FETCH CustomerBalance into aCustomerName,newbalance;
EXIT WHEN CustomerBalance%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line('CustomerName='||aCustomerName ||'balance='||newBalance);
END LOOP;
CLOSE CustomerBalance;

END;
/
```

any help is a appreciated

thanks

Comment: what database are you using? In what way doesn't it work, an error message or just unexpected result? Also why does the interest rate parameter have "out" after it? Seems like it should be a simple only parameter.

Comment: please add detailed description what error in what line do you have or why results you gettin are incorrect

Comment: this is Oracle (i do love its %TYPE)

Answer (score 0):

Seems most of the code is OK, you just have an extra `FETCH` just before the opening of the cursor, which should be deleted. Also, you lacked semicolon after the `newBalance` variable declaration. Other than that, you declared the `interestRate` parameter as `IN OUT`, but you don't seem to modify it anywhere. Still, this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addInterestNew(bank VARCHAR, interestRate INT out) AS

  CURSOR CustomerBalance IS
    SELECT customerName, balance
      FROM Deposit
    WHERE branchName = bank;

  aCustomerName Deposit.customerName%TYPE;
  newBalance  Deposit.balance%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  UPDATE DEPOSIT
    SET balance = balance * (1 + (interestRate/100))
  WHERE branchName = bank;

  OPEN CustomerBalance;

  LOOP
    FETCH CustomerBalance into aCustomerName,newbalance;
    EXIT WHEN CustomerBalance%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('CustomerName='||aCustomerName ||'balance='||newBalance);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE CustomerBalance;
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you soo much it worked, and yeah I did remove the 'out' in the parameter don't know how it got there